# Events are performed, but changes are not visible on UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I will describe my problem with an example.
I try to change `seekBar` progress using `seekBar.setProgress(value)`. I can get progress later using `seekbar.getProgress()`, but nothing changes on UI. I tried running it on in `runOnUIThread()`, but it didn't work. However, `Toast` is visible if I print right after the `seekBar.setProgress()`.

Maybe somebody has had similar problem?

```
seekBar.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", 5).show();
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        seekBar.postInvalidate();

        DevLog.d("RABL", seekBar.getContext().getClass().getSimpleName(), getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName(), progress, seekBar.getProgress(), "\n" +
                                        "=====================");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: we cant help without viewing your code

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you know that your code is "good" if the UI doen't update and you don't have error or warning

You need one of those two :

```
the_object_view.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
the_object_view.postInvalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. And notifyDataSetChanged cannot be called on View. It is in Adapter class.

Comment: Yes it is, but those too methods are the only methods to "update things". If it doesn't help the issu comes from your code

Comment: Yes, I hoped somebody had issue like that so it would be easier to find the cause.

Comment: Did you try with an asyntask ?

Comment: It accomplished nothing.